# Choroplethmapbox slow to render?

Tags: python, geojson, plotly-dash, choropleth

I’ve been playing around with Plotly and Dash for the first time over the past few days, with the hope of developing a browser-based data explorer for geographic NetCDF4 data. I’ve been impressed at how straightforward this has been so far, however I’m finding that some interactions with `choroplethmapbox` are taking longer to update and render than expected. I believe this may be the same issue discussed [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/choroplethmapbox-update-very-slow-when-deployed/37166)

The following refers to the code and sample data available [here](https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/nGWTSu40ouBYbu9), where the Dash application can be run using:
`python choropleth.py` (Python 3.7).

The source of my data comes from a 4D NetCDF4 file (in this case a model of ocean temperature - temp.nc) with dimensions of time, depth, lat and lon. In my case I’m only plotting a 2D chloropleth map, but I’d like the user to interactively select the desired time interval (and eventually depth) as well (the render will always be in 2D space).

Using the examples from [here](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/), I’m using a GeoJSON file of the 2D grid cells coupled with a Pandas DataFrame to render ocean temperature. Everything is working as expected, however any changes to the slider value (time) take a long time to update (approx six seconds on my machine). It appears as though there’s a second or so between selecting the slider value and running the `update_figure()` callback, then another 4-5 seconds before the new render starts to take place in the browser.

The `update_figure()` callback reads the requested data directly from the NetCDF4 file, then directly updates the Z values in the existing figure dictionary and returns this as a new figure (see code fragment below). At first I was concerned that the slow response time was due to reading from the NetCDF4, however a basic timing function shows that the `update_figure()` callback runs in less than 0.01 seconds in most cases. So it appears the delay is either coming from the `@app.callback` or the render function (post `update_figure()`) in Dash?

```
# Create the callback and callback function (update_figure)
@app.callback(Output('plot', 'figure'),
              [Input('slide', 'value')],
              [State('plot','relayoutData'),State('plot', 'figure')])
def update_figure(x,r,f):
    t0 = tme.time()
    f['layout']['mapbox']['center']['lat'] = f['layout']['mapbox']['center']['lat']
    f['layout']['mapbox']['center']['lon'] = f['layout']['mapbox']['center']['lon']
    f['layout']['mapbox']['zoom'] = f['layout']['mapbox']['zoom']

    # If the map window has been panned or zoomed, grab those values for the new figure
    if r is not None:
        if 'mapbox.center' in r:
            f['layout']['mapbox']['center']['lat'] = r['mapbox.center']['lat']
            f['layout']['mapbox']['center']['lon'] = r['mapbox.center']['lon']
            f['layout']['mapbox']['zoom'] = r['mapbox.zoom']

    # Extract the new time values from the NetCDF file
    tmp = nc['temp'][x, -1, :, :].values.flatten()
    # Repace the Z values in the original figure with the updated values, leave everything else (e.g. cell geojson and max/min ranges) as-is
    f['data'][0]['z'] = np.where(np.isnan(tmp), None, tmp).tolist()
    print("update_figure() time: ",tme.time()-t0)
    return f
```

I suspect that the slow render times are somehow related to the GeoJSON of each cell polygon (47k grid cell polygons are being rendered in total, with each polygon being defined by 6 points (i.e. 284k points total)), and unfortunately this can’t be simplified any further.

I'm seeking suggestions on how I can speed up the update/render when a user is interacting with the application. Two ideas I've had include:

1. Utilising WebGL if possible? It's unclear to me from the documentation whether `choroplethmapbox` already uses WebGL? If not, is there a pathway for making use of this for faster rendering?
2. Implementing some form of client side callback, although I don't know if this is possible given that I need to read the values directly out of the NetCDF file when requested by the user? Perhaps it's possible to just read/return the new Z values, then merge that with the existing GeoJSON on the client side?

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: This seems very interesting - have you tried asking the Dash forum or opening a ticket on GitHub? I wonder if it would get even more attention there.